# How to remove key of object array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `$variable` with an array like this, is there a way to remove the key "attributes" and make it a simple array?

````
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [attributes] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [FID] => 11
                    [Kode_Provi] => 31
                    [Provinsi] => DKI Jakarta
                    [Kasus_Posi] => 808
                    [Kasus_Semb] => 50
                    [Kasus_Meni] => 85
                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [attributes] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [FID] => 12
                    [Kode_Provi] => 32
                    [Provinsi] => Jawa Barat
                    [Kasus_Posi] => 220
                    [Kasus_Semb] => 11
                    [Kasus_Meni] => 21
                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [attributes] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [FID] => 16
                    [Kode_Provi] => 36
                    [Provinsi] => Banten
                    [Kasus_Posi] => 152
                    [Kasus_Semb] => 7
                    [Kasus_Meni] => 14
                )

        )

)
```                                                     .
````

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. You have an array of objects with properties there. You can not simply remove the "attributes key" because it actually represents a property of the object that is the value of the array at this point.

However, for the yes part, you can of course create an array out of your data structure and do not have objects on the levels anymore:

```php
// Example of input from the question
$innerValue = new stdClass();
$innerValue->FID = 12;
$innerValue->Kode_Provi = 32;

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->attributes = $innerValue;
$arr = [$obj];

// transforming it to array
$newArr = [];
foreach ($arr as $obj) {
    $innerArr = [];
    foreach ($obj->attributes as $prop => $value) {
        $innerArr[$prop] = $value;
    }
    $newArr[] = $innerArr;
}

var_dump($newArr);
```

output looks like this:

```php
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    'FID' =>
    int(12)
    'Kode_Provi' =>
    int(32)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to just remove 'attributes' key it's just simple:

```
<?php

    $variable = [

    (object) [
        'attributes' => (object) [
            'FID' => 11,
            'Kode_Provi' => 31,
            'Provinsi' => 'DKI Jakarta',
            'Kasus_Posi' => 808,
            'Kasus_Semb' => 50,
            'Kasus_Meni' => 85,
        ]
    ],

    (object) [
        'attributes' => (object) [
            'FID' => 12,
            'Kode_Provi' => 32,
            'Provinsi' => 'Jawa Barat',
            'Kasus_Posi' => 220,
            'Kasus_Semb' => 11,
            'Kasus_Meni' => 21,
        ]
    ]
];

$variable = array_map(
    function($item) {
        return $item->attributes;
    },
    $variable
);

print_r($variable);
```